# Error in Synchronizing Cookbooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

command

```
knife ec2 server create -r "role[test1]" -I ami-axxxxxe --flavor t1.micro -x ubuntu --ssh-key JP_Key --availability-zone us-east-1c -p 22 --tags Name=test_knife2 --iam test-role --subnet subnet-cxxxxx8 --associate-eip 5x.xx.xx.x -g sg-xxxx
```

Error:

```
10.220.15.110 Synchronizing Cookbooks:
================================================================================
10.220.15.110 Error Syncing Cookbooks:
================================================================================

https://mychefserver.example.com/bookshelf/organization00000000000000000000000000000000/
chcksum-d7c3b4577ca3ce35e757fb4a72c895f2?&Expires=1386685120&Signature=%2BaZMqKMbCxiBS5JuuaDgGO0HSRo%3D - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Your chef_server_url may be misconfigured
```

When I do `knife client list` in server output is the instance id of the chef client
problem here is client is not able to pull the recipes from server.

Comment: It looks like something is misconfigured. First of all, chef seems to think the cookbooks in the run-list are named '10.220.15.110', unless I'm misreading that. Can you show us your knife.rb (get rid of the sensitive information of course), and show us role[test1]? 

Otherwise, as I understand it, ```knife client list``` works, right? Can you run ```knife cookbook list``` ?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is with the domain "mychefserver.example.com". is this an externally accessible network alias? (From amazon?)

Comment: @DrewVS knife client list is working fine.

Comment: @DrewVS my knife.rblog_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'sala'
client_key               '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/sala.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/chef-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://10.220.15.158'
syntax_check_cache_path  '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
cookbook_path            '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks'

Comment: @MarkO'Conor  mychefserver.example.com is not externally accessible, it is the hostname of my server

Comment: what happens if i run 'chef-server-ctl reconfigure'

Comment: Umm... I would recommend removing your access_key_id from the output...

Answer (score 0):

When I've ran into this in the past it was due to a DNS issue with the new machine not being able to resolve the ChefServer.  For AWS/EC2 make sure the default DNS server that DHCP hands out will resolve correctly your chefserver.example.com domain name.